# Why isn't gps location working on samsung mobile?

Tags: android

I have done a program to fetch users gps location-its working fine in some mobiles but not working in Samsung S4(i9505).

I am running a service and extended LocationListener. Below is the code:

```
     public class MainService extends Service implements LocationListener
    { 
        public double latitude;
        public double longitude;

        LocationManager mlocManager=null;
        LocationListener mlocListener;

        Timer timer;

     @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
        {

            mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            mlocListener = this;
            mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

            if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) 
            {
                final String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                 // start new timer thread
                TimerTask task = new TimerTask() 
                {   
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        Location timerLoc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                        getFrndLocCloudAndSaveInDB();

                        SimpleDateFormat formata = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                        String currentDateandTime = formata.format(new Date());


                         if(latitude>0 & longitude>0)
                       {locObj = new LocModel(myName, String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude), currentDateandTime);

                        Log.d("ccrc","my Loc:::"+ String.valueOf(timerLoc.getLatitude()) + "  --|--  " + String.valueOf(timerLoc.getLongitude()) + "at" + currentDateandTime);}

                        i=i+1;
                        Log.d("ccrc","from timer--"+ i);

                    }
                };

                timer = new Timer(true);
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 5000, 10000); 


            }

         else {

           }

          return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        }


         @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
        {
            this.latitude=loc.getLatitude();
            this.longitude=loc.getLongitude();
            Log.i("latusrvc", String.valueOf(latitude));

        }

}
```

In Log-for ccrc tag i get the result in other mobiles but not showing the longitude and latitude in Samsung S4. Plus GPS is on- i have also checked that. What can be the problem really?

Comment: It should not happen. But if you say I can give you a nice code for getting latitude and longitude.

Comment: @Anshul Tyagi : That would be great!

Comment: do check if the LocationServices in the phone you are trying works in the first place. try opening Google Maps and see if it can acquire a fix (sometimes it takes minutes to get the first fix).

Comment: @ Angel Koh: i have checked that already. Google map works, plus i used the same place to check the location with samsung and another mobile.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this class to get latitude and longitude of the current location using `GPS` with method `canGetLocation()`. If `GPS` isn't on we can ask to activate the `GPS` of the phone by showing a `Dailog` with  method `showSettingsAlert`.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 2; // 10 meters
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 5 * 1; // 1 minute
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
 * app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
 * lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
    alertDialog
            .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks-its helpful. But its the same codes. So, why shouldn't mine work? weird!! Another queston-for Netwrok provider dont i have to enable the sim's data connection? i mean network provider will get data from my operator , so i have to enable sim's data connection- WIFI sont work in this case. right?

Comment: Your code isn't different. I cannot run your code right now. That's why I gave you a running code to keep working.

Comment: No, you don't need Sim's data connection because we can read some information of a valid sim card.